# How seq pattern matching works?

Tags: scala

I've below code snippet, it's always giving success, why?

```scala
object Basic {

    val basic = new Basic()
    val x = collection.mutable.Seq(2)

    def f(y : Seq[Int]): Unit = {
        y match {
            case `x` if {x(0) == 4; true}  => println("success")
        }
    }
    
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        f(Seq(2))
        f(Seq(2)) 
    }
}
```

In above code, `y` is something I'm passing `Seq(2)`
Once it enters in `f(y : Seq[Int])`, not able to understand this part `case x if {x(0) ==4; true}`

What is `x` here and from where is it coming?

Secondly, how `if` condition is working with `case` here, and how is it only able to return `Boolean`?

How can I understand this? I am new to Scala.

Answer (score 2):

> I've below code snippet, it's always giving success, why?

Because you are always returning `true` ...

> what is x here

Just a pointless alias to `y`, thus it is variable that holds `Seq(2)`

> and from where is it coming?

It is not coming from anywhere, you are creating it there.

> secondly, how if condition is working with case here, and how is it only able to return Boolean?

I am not sure how to answer that.

```scala
case <pattern> if <ward> =>
```

Is the syntax of the language, is like if you ask why `2 + 2` produces `4`. That is just how it works.

> not able to understand this part case x if {x(0) ==4; true}

So, you match on `y` then you use one of the simplest forms of pattern matching, an alias `x`. Then you go to a guard, that checks if the first element is a `4` *(note this is unsafe since the `Seq` may be empty)* and then ignores that result completely and just always success with a literal `true`.

Meaning the whole thing is pointless and is doing nothing at all; well it would crash if pass an empty `Seq` *(thus being even less useful than doing nothing at all)*.

> How can I understand this? I am new to Scala.

My advice would be that instead of looking at random code that is written in a confusing way *(this looks like a puzzler)*, rather pick a proper course or book or tutorial about the language and look for the pattern matching section.

Comment: updated my whole code, am confused to understand, how come x(0) == 4; is getting true ?

Comment: The first `x` is actually between backticks, so it's not an alias but the actual `x` value defined few lines above.

Comment: @GaëlJ, x(0) is , no ? How come x(0) which is 2  , is equals to 4 ?

Comment: `x(0) == 4` is `false` but it's not relevant as just after you forget about this value and return explicitly `true`. The whole `{...}` is a single expression with last expression being the returned value.

Comment: (my first comment was for Luis)

Comment: @GaëlJ so println("success") is else part of case statement ?

Comment: @OxanaGrey, sounds like you need to either chat with someone or read more about Scala. Stack overflow is not the right place for a long discussion.

Comment: `{ /* whatever */; true }` will always be `true` even if `whatever` is `false`.

Comment: @OxanaGrey no the block after a `match` is not the _"else"_, is rather the _"then"_ part. Again, it seems you don't even know the syntax of the language, not sure how you expect to understand some language just by looking at it, go a learn it.

Comment: @GaëlJ I am pretty sure that was changed, but maybe I just overlooked that detail, the whole code is a mess. Seems like a professor is trying to play smart and confuse their students. God, how I hate that kind of professors.